# Is there a way to determine if STDIN is a TTY through a system call?

Tags: linux, macos, assembly, system-calls

I know there is the `int isatty(int filedes)` function, but this in the standard C library. I want to determine if STDIN is a TTY by making a system call in Linux and OSX (I am writing a FORTH in assembly and I do not want to link to the C library).

Comment: The libc abstracts away most of the platform syscall differences. You might want to reconsider not using it or else you'll end up re-writing most of it.

Comment: Have you looked into the implementation of the libc to see how `isatty` is implemented?

Answer (score 3):

`isatty()` works by trying to execute [the TCGETS ioctl](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) on a file descriptor. If it succeeds, it's a TTY.

Comment: But in BSD flavors (as OS X) it is TIOCGETA, not TCGETS.